# Rating system with jQuery, PHP and SQL: Passing rated value from javascript to PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql

I'm meeting huge problems while creating a rating system for my website.
I have no problem with PHP, but with Javascpit and jQuery.

My intentions are to give the rated value to PHP, and, also give some other variables that are into the page URI (like: `?pg=try&id=2`).

Here what I do (and it work) util now:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

// START the RAtings script

    $('.ratingStars').hover(
        // Mouse Hover
        function() {
            $(this).prevAll().andSelf().addClass('overStar');
            $(this).nextAll().removeClass('voteStar');
        },
        // Handle teh mouseout
        function() {
            $(this).prevAll().andSelf().removeClass('overStar');
            set_votes($(this).parent());    
        }
    );
    // This make al clicable
    $('.ratingStars').bind('click', function() {
        ////// HERE THE CODE TO PHP
    });

});
```

I also need to know how to pass variables from PHP to Javascript...

Thanks in advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use AJAX to make a request to the backend.  Have a look at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Can I use Ajax also to make a request to PHP, and recive back a value? Ex: I request to the PHP the actual rating, and I recive back the value (by a function)

Comment: Yup.  It's 2-way.  You send a request to the backend and you get back a response.